# Could not find the java class name error - on online compilers

Tags: java

I didn't write any code. I just clicked test it now button in online tutorial sites. They had ready made program ready to be compiled. Still I'm getting the error as the class not found. Tried with many online compiler sites. Everywhere I'm getting the error. My PC have JDk,JRE etc properly installed.

[image]

Comment: u may want to add external libraries.

Comment: For online compiling??? How?

Comment: mention the site in which you are testing

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java_online.php

Comment: i think we cant add external library to online compilers like tutorials point. you may want to compile it in your system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The console output shows that you only try to execute your program. But in Java you first have to compile your class and then you can execute it.

Therefore press the compile button you you will see the `javac HelloWorld.java` appearing on the command line.

Comment: Worked like charm. Thank you brother